# How can I use jQuery in an Angular 8 app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular8

I have an application that utilizes SignalR to communicate with a desktop application. To utilize SignalR I need to use jQuery in my .ts file. However, it doesn't seem to work post migrating from Angular 7 to Angular 8.

I use `declare var $: any;` as I have in previous versions of Angular. Unfortunately, $ now prints blank to the console.

So, does Angular v8 no longer support using jQuery this way, or did something else break in the migration?

Update:

I have jQuery v3.3.1 loaded via npm.

This makes it global (in angular.json)

```
"scripts": [
         "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
         "./node_modules/signalr/jquery.signalR.js"
]
```

Comment: update your post on how you are actually using jquery and injecting it to your app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after stepping away from the issue for a bit and using roberts answer to confirm jQuery was working in app.module.ts (I wasn't aware a console.log would work in the middle of the imports), I realized I had fought this issue the last time I upgraded v4 to v7.

What had happened, is a dependency was causing jQuery to be reloaded. The section of the app that starts the signalR communication also loads another dependency (telerik-angular-report-viewer) which was causing console.log($) to display nothing because jQuery hadn't been loaded into the component yet.

The fix:

Remove the following code

```
window.jQuery = jQuery;
window.$ = jQuery;
```

from the following files

- dependencies\telerikReportViewer.kendo.min.js
- dependencies\telerikReportViewer.js
- cjs\telerik-report-viewer.component.js
- es\telerik-report-viewer.component.js

Comment: Tony’s answer was helpful, but didn’t exactly provide the fix. I accepted my answer because it provided with detail what exactly caused the problem and could help others that might run into a similar problem with other libraries.

Comment: You're asking X, but answering Y. You don't mention telerik in your question, and the 21 who upvoted Tony's probably don't use telerik either. And removing lines from a file is not always an option. The other answers are generic.

Comment: Actually, my question asked if it still works the way I was doing it or did something else break. The answer you want me to accept just provides a better way of loading jquery, but wouldn’t have fixed my problem (I tried). My answer, which I accepted, provided detail to my specific scenario and would help someone else who who may run into the same problem I did.

Answer (score 45):

More elegant way without using

```
declare var $: any;
```

First run

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install @types/jquery --save
```

Then in scripts section in architect => build of angular.json file add path for jquery lib

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
]
```

Then in your  tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["jquery"] // add here
  },
  "exclude": ["test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

So now you can use jquery anywhere in your project without using `declare var $ : any` for every file you need to use jquery

Comment: This is awesome! I don't use jQuery in my .ts files too often, so I do frequently forget to `declare var $: any;`

Comment: Yes it's key to add it in the tsconfig.app.json Previously I saw another answer to put it in the tsconfig.json file which didn't help.

Comment: ERROR in error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'jquery'.

Comment: @Stanley remove yarn-lock and package-lock.json file then run npm install again

Comment: if you use NX.Dev / libraries, then also add `"types": ["jquery"]` to the file: `tsconfig.lib.json` in each lib you want to use jquery in

Answer (score 7):

Angular 8 works with JQuery.

```
 "dependencies": {
  ...
  "jquery": "^3.4.1",
  ...
}
```

in your angular.json file import the required file like this:

```
"scripts": [
     "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
]
```

no `./` at the beginning, just `node_modules/...`

In your app.module verify it is working like this:

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

declare var $: any;
console.log(`jQuery version: ${$.fn.jquery}`);

@NgModule({
```

In the developer tools console it should print this:

jQuery version: 3.4.1

Comment: For some reason, my angular.json does require the `./` at the beginning of the script path.

Your answer did help me diagnose the problem at hand, which ended up being another package I had this issue with before. See my answer.

Comment: This is not a good solution as you declared `$` as any so you will have no type checking and intellisense...

Comment: @Mick share your solution