# Rails Webpacker - Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, webpack

I have a Rails 6 application and assets are compiled using `Webpack 4.39.1` ([Webpacker gem](https://github.com/rails/webpacker)) .

I have added `JQuery 3.4.1` and `Popper.js` to webpack `ProvidePlugin` as follows (`config/webpack/environment.js`):

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker');

const webpack = require('webpack');

environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}));

module.exports = environment;
```

I have a `javascript/packs/application.js` file and it is the entry point for webpack.

I have added `Bootstrap 4.1.1` and importing it to `application.js`.

Now, I'm trying to setup a tooltip as follows:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap";

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
        container: 'body',
        placement: 'auto'
    });
});
```

I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function` error in dev console.

I also checked `$.fn` and found none of the Bootstrap JS methods are part of JQuery prototype.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Did you restart the application?

Comment: yes, this is not working in development. I have restarted both puma and `webpack-dev-server`

Comment: You may need to import the tooltip. Add `import "bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip";` to application.js

Comment: Or remove all js you have imported about bootsrap in application.js, add only: `import "bootstrap";`

Comment: @demir : tried everything, still no luck!

Comment: @dp7 have you resolve the issue?

Comment: @prasannaboga were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: @dp7 were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: @Sivan yes. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60470917/tooltip-is-not-a-function-rails-6-webpack

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your webpack. Also install poper.js too

```
npm i popper.js
```

In your webpack

```
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
    }),
```

If you using ts add this in your typing.d.ts.

I'm also facing this same issue. After that to be sure restart IDE and your webpack again.

```
interface JQuery<any> {
    tooltip(params: any): any;
}
```

Comment: Have you fixed this issue with vanilla js ? I am not sure where to place this `typing.d.ts.` in a Rails - Webpacker setup.

Comment: Is that an acceptable answer? I'm struggling with "$ is not a function" error on Chrome console and not sure how to fix that.

Comment: @AskarHussain you can try with my answer or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56941924/angular-8-using-jquery/56944859#56944859

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by adding to your gemfile 'jquery-ui-rails' and 'jquery-ui-themes' Others have solved it by using import("bootstrap") in application.js