# ERROR in error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'jquery'.[Angular App] --

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, npm, angular8

I am building a pretty straightforward Angular web app. I need to incorporate some css and js files in my app as per a certain theme. Most of the js files are jquery plugins as you would expect.

So I installed the following --

```
npm i jquery --only=dev
npm i @types/jquery --save
```

Included this line in the imports segment:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

This is the dependencies section from my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.31",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
```

My main error is this --

```
ERROR in error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'jquery'.
```

So what's the trouble? I installed both the packages. I also tried by commenting out the @types/jquery line from the list of dependencies[after consulting some bug fix threads from github]. But No! It does not work! Neither solution worked for me. What's with the TS2688 error code for this one, could you please tell me? This is another thread I consulted --> [Angular 8 Using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56941924/angular-8-using-jquery)

What should I do? Which modification should I go for? Can you spot my error?
Apologies, if the question appears way too silly for you. Need help on this one,

Thanks,

Comment: My trouble is here -- I am trying to implement THIS theme in my angular app. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TQ2qMaqOx159EUeHib3kQnuM6vmtRYEM Naturally it contains js files [jquery based plugins]. SO I installed the relevant jquery packages in my Angular App. If you can straightaway replicate my scenario without any errors and load a default home page with some content my problem gets solved. SIMPLE. I have done a whole bunch of permutation combination of solutions but ZILCH works.   @sideshowbarker -- SOS.

Answer (score 0):

When u say u commented out the types line in package.json. Hope u removed the types package from ur node_modules as well.

Or Instead of

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Try

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

With types package installed.

Comment: yes I deleted the package from node_modules also. currently it is not there. ok let me just alter the import statement and see what happens.    @gkrthk

Comment: No. I did a proper npm uninstall of @types/jquery to make sure. Also replaced my import line with yours. But no. Still getting the same error in CLI. And in the chrome console getting the following errors: 

** Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:4200/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

** Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
??  @gkrthk

Comment: pls find my latest comment under the original answer  @gkrthk

Comment: can u share a stackblitz.

Comment: will try but I am not sure I can add and reference and then use all of those css js scss files in my stackblitz replication.    @gkrthk . You can see the theme for yourself, in that link -->

drive.google.com/open?id=1TQ2qMaqOx159EUeHib3kQnuM6vmtRYEM