# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in

Tags: jquery, angular, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic and it mode of operation. I read tutorials here and there which made me tried to create my own app. In my app I am trying to add **auto-complete module** using **jquery-ui** but when I tried running the app the following errors displayed.

I have done the following:

```
npm install @types/jquery@2.0.47 --save-dev
npm install --save jquery jquery-ui
```

In my .ts, I have

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
import 'jqueryui';

ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Get search box parameter
        $('#search_data').autocomplete({
            source: "/api/searchStaff.php",
            minLength: 1,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $('#search_data').val(ui.item.value);
            }
        }).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $("<li class='ui-autocomplete-row'></li>")
                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append(item.label)
                .appendTo(ul);
        };
    });
}
```

I add jquery aliased to resolve with the plugin in the webpack.config.js

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        "$": "jquery",
        "jQuery": "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    }),
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            // bind version of jquery-ui
            "jquery-ui": "jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js",
            // bind to modules;
            modules: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules"),
```

> [15:33:14]  ionic-app-script task: "build" [15:33:14]  Error:
>   ./node_modules/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'jquery' in
>               'c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jqueryui' resolve 'jquery' in 'c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jqueryui' Parsed request
>               is a module using description file: c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jqueryui\package.json (relative path: .)
>   Field
>               'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration after using description file:
>               c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jqueryui\package.json (relative path: .) resolve as module looking for modules in
>               c:\iVisitor\node_modules using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
>               Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration after using description file:
>               c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json
>               (relative path: ./node_modules/jquery) no extension Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias
>               configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist .ts Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid
>               alias configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts doesn't exist .js Field 'browser' doesn't contain a
>               valid alias configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js doesn't exist .json Field 'browser'
>   doesn't
>               contain a valid alias configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json doesn't exist as directory
>               c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist looking for modules in c:\iVisitor\node_modules using
>               description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) Field 'browser' doesn't contain a
>               valid alias configuration after using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path:
>               ./node_modules) using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/jquery) no
>               extension Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery
>               doesn't exist .ts Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>               c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts doesn't exist .js Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias
>               configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js doesn't exist .json Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid
>               alias configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json doesn't exist as directory
>               c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist looking for modules in c:\iVisitor\node_modules using
>               description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) Field 'browser' doesn't contain a
>               valid alias configuration after using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path:
>               ./node_modules) using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/jquery) no
>               extension Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery
>               doesn't exist .ts Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>               c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts doesn't exist .js Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias
>               configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js doesn't exist .json Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid
>               alias configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json doesn't exist as directory
>               c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist looking for modules in c:\iVisitor\node_modules using
>               description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) Field 'browser' doesn't contain a
>               valid alias configuration after using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path:
>               ./node_modules) using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/jquery) no
>               extension Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery
>               doesn't exist .ts Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>               c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts doesn't exist .js Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias
>               configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js doesn't exist .json Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid
>               alias configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json doesn't exist as directory
>               c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery]
>               [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery]
>               [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts]
>               [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts]
>               [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js]
>               [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js]
>               [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json]
>               [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json]
>               [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery]
>               [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery] @ ./node_modules/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js 10:2-32 @
>               ./src/pages/register/register.ts @ ./src/app/app.module.ts @
>               ./src/app/main.ts,./src/pages/register/register.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in
>               'c:\iVisitor\src\pages\register' resolve 'jquery' in 'c:\iVisitor\src\pages\register' Parsed request is a
>               module using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./src/pages/register) Field
>               'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration after using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json
>               (relative path: ./src/pages/register) resolve as module looking for modules in c:\iVisitor\node_modules
>               using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) Field 'browser' doesn't
>               contain a valid alias configuration after using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path:
>               ./node_modules) using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/jquery) no
>               extension Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery
>               doesn't exist .ts Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>               c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts doesn't exist .js Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias
>               configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js doesn't exist .json Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid
>               alias configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json doesn't exist as directory
>               c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist looking for modules in c:\iVisitor\node_modules using
>               description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) Field 'browser' doesn't contain a
>               valid alias configuration after using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path:
>               ./node_modules) using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/jquery) no
>               extension Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery
>               doesn't exist .ts Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>               c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts doesn't exist .js Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias
>               configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js doesn't exist .json Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid
>               alias configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json doesn't exist as directory
>               c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist looking for modules in c:\iVisitor\node_modules using
>               description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) Field 'browser' doesn't contain a
>               valid alias configuration after using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path:
>               ./node_modules) using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/jquery) no
>               extension Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery
>               doesn't exist .ts Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>               c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts doesn't exist .js Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias
>               configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js doesn't exist .json Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid
>               alias configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json doesn't exist as directory
>               c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist looking for modules in c:\iVisitor\node_modules using
>               description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) Field 'browser' doesn't contain a
>               valid alias configuration after using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path:
>               ./node_modules) using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/jquery) no
>               extension Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery
>               doesn't exist .ts Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>               c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts doesn't exist .js Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias
>               configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js doesn't exist .json Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid
>               alias configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json doesn't exist as directory
>               c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist looking for modules in c:\iVisitor\node_modules using
>               description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) Field 'browser' doesn't contain a
>               valid alias configuration after using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path:
>               ./node_modules) using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/jquery) no
>               extension Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery
>               doesn't exist .ts Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>               c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts doesn't exist .js Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias
>               configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js doesn't exist .json Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid
>               alias configuration c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json doesn't exist as directory
>               c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery]
>               [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery]
>               [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts]
>               [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts]
>               [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js]
>               [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js]
>               [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js]
>               [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json]
>               [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json]
>               [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery]
>               [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery] @
>               ./src/pages/register/register.ts 53:0-28 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts @ ./src/app/main.ts Error:
>   ./node_modules/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'jquery' in 'c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jqueryui' resolve
>   'jquery' in 'c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jqueryui'   Parsed request is a
>   module   using description file:
>   c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jqueryui\package.json (relative path: .)
>       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration   after using description file:
>   c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jqueryui\package.json (relative path: .)
>       resolve as module
>         looking for modules in c:\iVisitor\node_modules
>           using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
>             Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           after using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
>             using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/jquery)
>               no extension
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist
>               .ts
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts doesn't exist
>               .js
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js doesn't exist
>               .json
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json doesn't exist
>               as directory
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist
>         looking for modules in c:\iVisitor\node_modules
>           using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
>             Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           after using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
>             using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/jquery)
>               no extension
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist
>               .ts
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts doesn't exist
>               .js
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js doesn't exist
>               .json
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json doesn't exist
>               as directory
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist
>         looking for modules in c:\iVisitor\node_modules
>           using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
>             Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           after using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
>             using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/jquery)
>               no extension
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist
>               .ts
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts doesn't exist
>               .js
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js doesn't exist
>               .json
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json doesn't exist
>               as directory
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist
>         looking for modules in c:\iVisitor\node_modules
>           using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
>             Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           after using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
>             using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/jquery)
>               no extension
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist
>               .ts
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts doesn't exist
>               .js
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js doesn't exist
>               .json
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json doesn't exist
>               as directory
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery]  @
>   ./node_modules/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js 10:2-32  @
>   ./src/pages/register/register.ts  @ ./src/app/app.module.ts  @
>   ./src/app/main.ts,./src/pages/register/register.ts Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in 'c:\iVisitor\src\pages\register'
>   resolve 'jquery' in 'c:\iVisitor\src\pages\register'   Parsed request
>   is a module   using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json
>   (relative path: ./src/pages/register)
>       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration   after using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path:
>   ./src/pages/register)
>       resolve as module
>         looking for modules in c:\iVisitor\node_modules
>           using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
>             Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           after using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
>             using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/jquery)
>               no extension
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist
>               .ts
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts doesn't exist
>               .js
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js doesn't exist
>               .json
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json doesn't exist
>               as directory
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist
>         looking for modules in c:\iVisitor\node_modules
>           using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
>             Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           after using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
>             using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/jquery)
>               no extension
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist
>               .ts
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts doesn't exist
>               .js
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js doesn't exist
>               .json
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json doesn't exist
>               as directory
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist
>         looking for modules in c:\iVisitor\node_modules
>           using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
>             Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           after using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
>             using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/jquery)
>               no extension
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist
>               .ts
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts doesn't exist
>               .js
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js doesn't exist
>               .json
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json doesn't exist
>               as directory
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist
>         looking for modules in c:\iVisitor\node_modules
>           using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
>             Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           after using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
>             using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/jquery)
>               no extension
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist
>               .ts
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts doesn't exist
>               .js
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js doesn't exist
>               .json
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json doesn't exist
>               as directory
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist
>         looking for modules in c:\iVisitor\node_modules
>           using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
>             Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           after using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
>             using description file: c:\iVisitor\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/jquery)
>               no extension
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist
>               .ts
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts doesn't exist
>               .js
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js doesn't exist
>               .json
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json doesn't exist
>               as directory
>                 c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.ts]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.js]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery.json]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery] [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery]
>   [c:\iVisitor\node_modules\jquery]  @ ./src/pages/register/register.ts
>   53:0-28  @ ./src/app/app.module.ts  @ ./src/app/main.ts
>       at new BuildError (c:\iVisitor\node_modules@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\errors.js:16:28)
>       at callback (c:\iVisitor\node_modules@ionic\app-scripts\dist\webpack.js:121:28)
>       at emitRecords.err (c:\iVisitor\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:265:13)
>       at Compiler.emitRecords (c:\iVisitor\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:371:38)
>       at emitAssets.err (c:\iVisitor\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:258:10)
>       at applyPluginsAsyncSeries1.err (c:\iVisitor\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:364:12)
>       at next (c:\iVisitor\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:218:11)
>       at Compiler.compiler.plugin (c:\iVisitor\node_modules\webpack\lib\performance\SizeLimitsPlugin.js:99:4)
>       at Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries1 (c:\iVisitor\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:222:13)
>       at Compiler.afterEmit (c:\iVisitor\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:361:9) [ERROR] An
>   error occurred while running subprocess ionic-app-scripts.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Trying to use jQuery with Angular is opening up a whole world of pain. Angular really likes to own the DOM manipulation, and if you're using jQuery to also manipulate the DOM, you're going to run into trouble without extreme care. Have you explored the "Angular" way of doing this?

Comment: @KurtHamilton, No. Could you please point me to the right direction.

Comment: I've not used any autocomplete libraries, but I would start off by doing a Google search for this. Some UI frameworks (like Material and ng-bootstrap) come with the functionality. If you don't want to commit to a UI framework, you can probably find thousands of standalone libraries. This is the first one I found: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ng-autocomplete, which looks fairly well supported

Comment: @KurtHamilton, Thanks. I'll look into it and get back to you.

Comment: Not recommend you using jquery with angular but here is my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56941924/angular-8-using-jquery/56944859#56944859) show how to install jquery in angular

Answer (score -1):

try installing jquery on npm, it should solve it. I had that issue on react.js